# Highstock rangeSelector and series.points in future

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a few series data which are > today (e.g. 11.03.2014 - 31.05.2014) and I am facing 2 problems right now:

1. If I am using the rangeSelector 1y everything works fine, highcharts displays series correctly (11.03.2013 - 11.03.2014) BUT if I am selecting ALL in the rangeSelector and then 1y again, highcharts displays series from 31.05.2013 - 31.05.2014. Is ther any possibility to prevent selecting series > today?
2. Same situation as described but now I make use of series.points - the problem is, I dont have data of series "xy" in the future which leads to an highstock error   `TypeError: b is undefined`. I tried to fix it with a simple if condition: `if(xy.points.length > 0)`, but it still throws an error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle, please. Otherwise it's hard to guess what is wrong.

Comment: Here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/L6vg8/   Removed some series to reduce the amount of data, so dont wonder why I am using a loop to add the data to an array which is used for the chart.

Comment: it seems like a general problem with handling days in the future - is it possible to realize something like that in general with highcharts?

Comment: Your jsFiddle doesn't run...

Comment: Need to change onLoad in left dropdown. Anyway, still there are errors in console: http://jsfiddle.net/L6vg8/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3js9u/2/ doesnt display the chart, still dont know why - it should work. but maybe u could just review the code especially the function afterSetExtremes. could attache screenshots as well

Comment: In general you don't run createChart in any place.

Comment: its kinda hard to get it works, I cant reconstruct my code 1:1 because Im working with 10-30mb of series data. Is there no possibility for you to review the code and guess what is going wrong?

Comment: Honestly Im not see your code, so how we can debug it?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/3js9u/2 the after set extreme function, u cant see it?

Comment: So you are trying to set new extremes in `afterSetExtremes` event? Smells like infinite loop..